# How to track formula field which is related with different objects?

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field, field-history

I have one formula field on `Opportunity` which is the calculation of the Revenue from the

`SubscriptionFee__c` object + Rate from the `Rate__c` object.

In `Opportunity`, we want to track the history of this formula, so when this changes, it should display in the History.

I have made one custom field called `Expected Revenue history` and created one *workflow rule* with

- Rule Criteria: `ISCHANGED(ExpectedRevenue__c) //formula field on Oppt`
- Evaluation Criteria: `created, and every time it's edited`
- Field to Update: `Expected Revenue history`
- Specify New Field Value: `ExpectedRevenue__c`

I have put this new field on history tracking, but when I change the related fields - the new field is not changing.

How can I write a trigger to update this field?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your workflow is on Opportunity, the opportunity will never have a DML event when its related objects `SubscriptionFee__c` or `Rate__c` objects change values.

That is, a workflow on Opportunity doesn't monitor changes on related object fields that influence the value of Opportunity formula fields.

A workaround is to add after-save Flows to both the `SubscriptionFee__c` and `Rate__c` objects so that when they change, you then Get (query) for the related Opportunity(s) and then update the Opportunity(s)' `Expected Revenue History`

Answer (score 0):

Formula fields cannot be tracked as the value of this field is calculated on runtime, and it is not saved to database. So the value is calculated for example when user opens the record detail page or upon query from database.

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_formula_where.htm&type=5)

[image]

If you want some work around, you would have to create a trigger and upon update of any fields which is coming into your formula you will capture the new value.